# Booting Debian affects internet connectivity of other devices in same LAN network

Tags: networking, debian, lan

I'm currently having issues running Debian on a desktop computer, particularly network issues.

After 10 attempts of running the Debian installer, I've managed to install Debian on the desktop computer (whose partitioning type is MBR).

However, as soon as I start Debian, the entire local area network almost freezes and becomes unresponsive in few minutes. The computer itself is affected too, which makes it hard to connect remotely to the problematic computer.

The computer seems to flood the network when Debian is loaded by computer. How can this be possible, and how can I fix this issue? Thank you for reading this.

If it matters, I've used two physical partition. (LVM for /home, /var, /tmp and ext4 for /)

**EDIT**: The local network is connected to Internet via a modem, and both a wireless router and the computer is connected to the modem. I currently cannot boot the OS as I don't have access to that computer now.

Comment: Can you provide some detail about the network and how everything is connected, other computers, computer you're referring to, etc.  If you think the Debian install problems are related, describe them.  Have you run any diagnostics?  Does the network resume normal performance at some point?  How is the computer, itself, affected?

Comment: @fixer1234 Unfortunately, I currently does not have access to that computer since it is not my own. I'll post the information as soon as possible once I gain access to it.